# Combine multiple result together in Hibernate

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, java-8

I'm writing a query with multiple joins in Hibernate.
Now I need to query all the models and related products that uses some item.

I created the hql query and it looks like:

```
"FROM Model m inner join fetch m.products p inner join p.itemsInProducts iip inner join iip.item i where i.number = '" + itemID + "' and m.active = '1' and p.active = '1' and iip.active = '1'"
```

It gives me some results back. But I have multiple Model object that are the same but with a different product. Is there some way to combine all the Model objects and place the Product in the same Model?

My variables in the Model class looks like:

```
public class Model implements java.io.Serializable {

    private long id;
    private ItemClass itemClass;
    private OrderProcessorCode orderProcessorCode;
    private String name;
    private boolean active;
    private long companyId;
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set products = new HashSet(0);
    private Set itemsConsumedPerModels = new HashSet(0);
    private Set itemsInModels = new HashSet(0);
```

And product:

```
public class Product implements java.io.Serializable {

    private long id;
    private ItemClass itemClass;
    private ItemType itemType;
    private OrderProcessorCode orderProcessorCode;
    private String number;
    private String description;
    private boolean baseProduct;
    private boolean otmProduct;
    private boolean active;
    private long companyId;
    private Set itemsInProducts = new HashSet(0);
    @JsonBackReference(value = "product-models")
    private Set models = new HashSet(0);
    private Set optionsPerProductsForProductId = new HashSet(0);
    private Set optionsPerProductsForOptionId = new HashSet(0);
    private Set productionOrders = new HashSet(0);
```

Comment: How about removing "WHERE" clause ?

Comment: The where clause is correct. I changed my code to manually merge the model objects into a couple of for loops. But I don't think this is the best sollution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my query and code a little. Now all the queried products are automatically added to the models.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Model m inner join fetch m.products p inner join p.itemsInProducts iip inner join iip.item i where i.number = '" + itemID +"'  and m.active = '1' and p.active = '1' and iip.active = '1'");

        ArrayList<Object[]> items = (ArrayList<Object[]>) query.list();

        session.close();

        for (Object[] objects : items) {
            Model tempModel = (Model) objects[0];

            if(!allmodels.contains(tempModel))
            {
                allmodels.add(tempModel);
            }
        }
```